# Formatting input text while typing by adding a decimal point after 3 chars in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I format a number while typing in my React form component? I have tried this with the below code [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2z19y9p24r), and it works fine when I try to show the value on the page, but the formatting is not working as expected when I try it on input field like this: `value={this.state.hello}`.

is there any best way to solve this , if it is not the right way ?

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Button from "./button";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  insertDecimal = num => (Number(num) / 1000).toFixed(3);

  onchangeHandler = event => {
    let fieldName = event.target.name;
    let fieldVal = event.target.value;
    const formattedVal = this.insertDecimal(fieldVal);
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [fieldName]: formattedVal });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("state : ", this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="hello"
          value={this.state.hello}
          onChange={this.onchangeHandler}
        />
        {this.state.hello}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value formatting is dividing the input by 1,000. When a user enters `3`, the output is `0.003`. When they enter an additional digit the new value of `0.003N` is divided by 1,000 again, resulting in something like `0.0000031`, which you're rounding to a scale of 3, resulting in `0.000`.

Comment: is there any better way to get the expected result